# what are the dotnet libraries for convex optimization?

Tags: .net, optimization, f#, convex-optimization, convex

Would you recommend any convex optim libraries ?

Ideally opensource.
A priori for semidefinite programming and QCQP.

(I intend to use it with fsharp but any dotnet would do)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/abfd6945-442e-4c56-8ce0-65c0c2748845

Comment: You should have posted that as an answer @Daniel

Comment: @ildjarn : convex optimization is quite specific. from what I saw, there aren't so many libraries providing it, so SO wont be flooded by vendors on this,

Comment: That doesn't make it any less off-topic. ;-]

Comment: @ildjam would you recommend a place where I can inquire on the subject of finding a good quadratic programming library ?

Comment: [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) would be a step in the right direction. :-]

Comment: what would be the best destination ? and why is that more off-topic than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426/graphing-javascript-library ? you are probably right but I just dont see why

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: indeed, the link makes sense. but if there was libraries of CO shipped as frequently as there are 'Canon S90 and Lumix LX3' updates, I probably would not even bother asking

Comment: @nicolas: I would recommend [Solver Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524509(v=vs.93).aspx). They have developed a domain specific language for optimization using F# quotations. It is extremely convenient if you use F#.

Comment: Hi pad this one seems to have cvx opt indeed! I did not know msft had a solver like that...I am looking its capacities

Comment: @nicolas: Yes, they have. For getting started with F# and Solver Foundation, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318609/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-in-microsoft-solver-foundation-vs-matlab-fmin) and [this blog post](http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2008/09/21/1628.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Solver Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh145003), a .Net runtime for mathematical programming, modeling, and optimization from Microsoft, probably provides what you want.

They also have [Optimization Modeling Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524507%28v=vs.93%29.aspx) which allows to model optimization problems in a declarative way. This way of modeling is really attractive when combining with expressiveness of functional programming languages like F#.

To get a feeling of using Solver Foundation with F#, take a look at these interesting blog posts:

- [Solvers, Optimization, and more on DSLs](http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2008/09/21/1628.aspx)
- [Optimization domain specific language in F# with units of measure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lengningliu/archive/2009/09/04/optimization-domain-specific-language-in-f-with-units-of-measure.aspx)
- [Support vector machines (SVMs) in F# using Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2011/02/support-vector-machines-svms-in-f-using.html)